# Android PreferenceManager without visual component?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get a **SharedPreferences** object from the **PreferenceManager** but don't want to pass in the **Context** to the class.

Can I get a "global" context from inside my class?

```
SharedPreferences pref = 
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Some Global Context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally have a reference to a context from any major component of your application (Activity, Service, etc...)  If this is a utility class then passing a reference of a context should suffice.

Is there a particular pattern you are trying to implement.. or avoid implementing?